# Is it okay to ask a question deliberately and answer it almost instantly?

Tags: discussion

I have been playing around with Raspberry Pis for close to a year now and I have a keen interest in **Ad-Hoc** operations in wireless mediums. I have recently found out that a **USB-Wireless Dongles** with `r8188eu` driver modules are compatible to work in the aforementioned mode of operation. This, of course, comes with a certain steps that are required to configure the dongle and would like to share this information on the RPI_SE.

Is it wise to ask a question by oneself and immediately go ahead and answer it, with the whole thread's purpose of being an informative one?

Comment: You can also use the button labeled "Answer your own question" to post an answer at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

Yes! Please do. [There's no problem with that whatsoever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), provided that both the question and the answer meet all the usual prerequisites. I'd perhaps add the caveat that you should be open to the possibility that someone else has an *even better* answer, and to keep an open mind on whose is best when it comes time to choose which is 'most right'.

Comment: Of course I will not accept the answer since it can change but the thread is open for new and improved answers

Comment: You should go ahead and accept your own answer if you feel it answers the question. Treat it no differently to any other question you've asked - evaluate all the submitted options and if one fits the bill, that's your answer regardless of who wrote it.

Comment: Remember also, you can change the accepted answer later if a better one comes along.

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest that you prepare your answer alongside with the question, so you can post both almost simultaneously? Or perhaps add a `[resolved]` label to the question title, which you could later remove?

Many times I've found myself researching a recently posted question, only to find out 5 minutes later that it was of a self-answered kind and my effort was wasted.

Comment: I agree with you. I am actually preparing the answer and the moment I finish it, I will post the question and answer immediately

Comment: In fact there should be a checkbox on the interface (not sure if there is a reputation hurdle to cross) at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page that says, *"Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"*.  If you select this you will get two edit boxes, one for the question and one for the answer, so you can prepare them together and post all at once.

Comment: @goldilocks In its absence, I would just type both in the question field, then cut the answer part before posting the question and past it in the answer field moments later.